# Facebook "just login" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using 'send-to-messenger' button, which doesn't appear when user is not logged in. I want to display Facebook login(**no authentication**) button. I would like this button to display ordinary Facebook login dialog.

Is there any way to do that? I'm aware of Facebook login, but this is authentication process, and I wan't the user only to be logged in.

Edit:

Send-to-messenger button is rendered by Facebook's JS_sdk

Comment: can you please show some the code that you have written

Comment: No, there is no button or plugin to just log the user in to Facebook.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any solution yet therefore I don't have any actual code for the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like at the moment Facebook does not provide a login button.

I found that easiest way was to write a href button which calls facebook login url and asks user. Once user is logged-in my page is re-freshed